# c# casting idea explanation

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

i am studying C# online , and i faced this thing a couldn't understand it ,
consider this Animal class

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Age { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public double Weight { set; get; }

    public Animal()
    { }

    public Animal(int Age, string Name, double Weight)
    {
        this.Age = Age;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Weight = Weight;
    } 
}
```

And the Dog class which inherit from Animal

```
class Dog : Animal
{
    public string color { set; get; }

    public Dog()
    {
    }

    public Dog(int Age, string Name, double Weight, string color) : base(Age, Name, Weight)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public string EmptyMethod()
    {
        return(" i am dog method ");
    }
}
```

In the Main method in program class

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Animal> MyAnimals = new List<Animal>();
        List<Dog> MyDogs = new List<Dog>();

        MyAnimals.Add(new Animal());
        MyAnimals.Add(new Dog());

        foreach (var item in MyAnimals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().Name);
            if (item is Dog)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().Name + " i am dog between Animal");
              //Here i got a compiling error and can't reach the dog empty method even after checking it's a Dog object !!! Why
             var tryingToReachDogMethod = item.EmptyMethod();

            }
        }

        Animal smallAnimal = new Animal();
        MyDogs.Add(new Dog());
        MyDogs.Add(smallAnimal as Dog);

        foreach (var item in MyDogs)
        {
            //Here i Can reach the Empty Method from Dog Class !!!
            //i know it will give runtime error because some objects is not 
            //dogs and don't have it's method to implement it 
            var tryingToReachDogMethod = item.EmptyMethod();

            if (item is Animal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i am animal as dog");
            }
        }
```

I comment My question in the third piece of code ,(the code is one of my exercises i have written few days ago) , so why would a programmer make a list of animals then put a more developed object in it (in the example object from class dog) and why any one would to do the opposite ? why to make a list from developed object (in the example dogs) and then try to put Less developed type of objects in it ,
Can you give example from real programming solution

Comment: There are a lot of questions in this question. Look up polymorphism in relation to programming. Read up on inheritance, and on virtual methods.

Comment: the main one is why to cast ?Whats the benefit ? could you suggest  example from real programming solution ?

Comment: That one is just you misunderstanding what `is` as an operator does. Read up on c# then.

Comment: @Mohamed the benefit ist that you can have a list of animals, Cats, Dogs whatever and store them all in one list if you dont need their specifics. if you want to ged a trait only a dog has you can later say all animals where typ is Dog.. its enables you to put different classes into one list (like object does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyDogs` is a list of dogs. You can add only `Dog`s to it.

The problem is in this line:

```
MyDogs.Add(smallAnimal as Dog);
```

You probably think you casted the animal to a dog. That is not true. You tried to cast it, but it failed. Since you use `as`, it will not throw an exception, but instead will return `null`. Now you have a `null` `Dog` in your list. You will get a null reference exception when you try to access members of that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Cause `item` is still `Animal` since you have `List<Animal> MyAnimals = new List<Animal>();` and your `Animal` type don't have a `EmptyMethod()`. Thus you need to cast it to `Dog` type explicitly like below in order to invoke the desired method

```
var tryingToReachDogMethod = ((Dog)item).EmptyMethod()
```

(Or) You can as well use `as` operator along with null propagation operator like

```
Dog d = item as Dog;
var tryingToReachDogMethod = d?.EmptyMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Real world example of where it makes sense to put a (as you call it) "more developed" version of an object inside a list defined using a base class or interface is the "Command" pattern.

Given an interface like this:

```
public interface ICommand 
{
    void Execute();
}
```

You might have lots of different implementations of `ICommand` that you want to execute one after another. You would put them all in some sort of List

```
var commands = new List<ICommand>();
commands.Add(new Command1());
commands.Add(new Command2());
```

And execute them all. You dont need to know what sort of command it is, just that they all have an `Execute` method

```
foreach(var command in commands)
     command.Execute();
```

This demonstrates [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))